# How can I loop over array of objects in a function?

Tags: javascript, function, foreach

I have an array of objects, and I want to loop over certain values in the objects. I tried to build a function for this, but am getting undefined back. What am I doing wrong here?

The Array:

```js
let clauseArray = [
    {
        clauseID: 0,
        clauseText: "text clause ",
    },

    {
        clauseID: 1,
        clauseText: "text clause ",
    },
    {
        clauseID: 2,
        clauseText: "text clause ",
    },
    {
        clauseID: 3,
        clauseText: "text clause ",
    },
];
```

And the function:

```js
let displayClauses = function () {
    clauseArray.forEach((clause) => clause.clauseText);
};
```

Comment: You *are* looping over the array of objects, but you're not returning anything. Also forEach doesn't return anything for you to return.

Comment: What *do* you want to get as output? And where do you want the output to be displayed (HTML document, console, file, ...)

Comment: Try reading articles first like this one: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-loops-explained-for-loop-for .

If you want to know more about `forEach` and other Array methods [check mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let clauseArray = [
  {
    clauseID: 0,
clauseText:
"text clause ", 
  },

  {
    clauseID: 1,
    clauseText:
    "text clause ", 
  },
  {
    clauseID: 2,
    clauseText:
    "text clause ",    
  },
  {
    clauseID: 3,
    clauseText:
    "text clause ", 
  },
];

for (let value of clauseArray ) {
  
  console.log(value.text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response everyone. Really helpful. forEach is just looping over the array but not returning anything. :-) I know how to proceed from here.

Learning to code is an uphill battle.